# empaquetar proyecto python dentro de un .exe

Tags: python

Buenos dias, 
quiero  empaquetar un proyecto python dentro de 1 exe 
se que con pyinstaller y py2exe se puede hacer pero necesito 
que solamente genere 1 exe y no las 
otras librerias que generan dichos programas 
muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Necesitas que sea un único exe, o te valdría un setup.exe que instala (o descomprime) los binarios?

Comment: seria mejor un unico exe pero bueno si no hay de otra....

Answer (score 1):

Si tu programa tiene dependencias o archivos externos a Python puedes utilizar [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) y seleccionar la opción de "single EXE".

Aunque tal y como comenta [FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51028/18003), puedes configurar P2exe y PyInstaller directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Tanto [**py2exe**](http://www.py2exe.org/) como [**PyInstaller**](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) permiten crear ejecutables empaquetados integramente en un `exe` sin dependencias externas. Para ello solo hay que especificarlo con los parámetros oportunos.

En el caso de **PyInstaller** debes especificar la opción `--onefile` o `-f`.

El uso básico de **PyInstaller** es:

- Lo instalamos, para ello podemos usar `pip`, en my caso dado que tengo varias versiones de Python abro la consola (CMD en Windows) y:

  ```
  py -3.5 -m pip install pyinstaller
  ```

  (Esto intala PyInstaller en Python 3.5)
- Nos situamos en el directorio donde esté nuestro módulo python y creamos el `exe` escribiendo en la consola (CMD en Windows):

  ```
  pyinstaller nombreDelScript.py --onefile
  ```

PyInstaller trae muchas más opciones (encriptación, cambio del icono y nombre del exe, versión, etc ), puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) para ver todas las posibilidades. Si usas paquetes externos a la biblioteca estándar de Python te aconsejo que te mires los [paquetes soportados](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) por PyInstaller.

Si todo va bién se creará el ejecutable en el mismo directorio donde estás situado. El exe se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `dist`, el resto de archivos creados fuera de esta carpeta son usados por PyInstaller en el proceso de empaquetado pero tu solo necesitas el conteneido de la carpeta `dist`, que en este caso tal y como especificamos es un solo ejecutable que puedes usar donde quieras sin otras dependencias externas.

Si no usas la opción `--onefile` observaras que se te crea un directorio dentro de `dist` que contiene el exe pero además encontrarás otros archivos como ficheros `pyd` o `dll` ya que si no especificas nada PyInstaller funciona en modo onedir.

Comment: lo hice de la forma que me explico y probe el .exe que mostraba un mensaje en otra maquina donde no habia nada de python y me dio error pues necesitaba unas dll de win

Comment: @logancale2016 Intenta crear el ejecutable sin usar `--onefile` (`pyinstaller nombreDelScript.py`) y prueba a ejecutarlo en la otra máquina (tienes que copiar la carpeta completa que se crea en `dist` en este caso). Mira a ver si de esta dorma te da error o no. Estaría bien conocer que librerias usas, tu código (si es posible y no muy largo) o al menos un ejemplo mínimo que te reproduzca el mismo error para poder reproducir el problema. A ciegas es difícil orientarte, estos problemas no son raro al intnetar crear un `exe`, no deja de ser una forma 'antinatural' de ejecutar código interpretado.

Comment: Puedes echar un vistazo a [esto](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly) para intentar ver si todo se empaqueta correctamente. Como digo intenta aportar algo más de información a ver si te podemos ayudar, muchas veces esto se debe al uso de librerias externas, módulos cython, etc